# Notepad++ regex replace print( stuff ); with echo stuff;

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to do a notpad++ replace with regex but I can't figure out how to do it.

search:    print( **ignore this stuff** );

replace:   echo **ignored stuff** ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Find :-

```
print\((.*)\)
```

Replace with :-

```
echo \1
```

EDIT2:

1. Use **.* to match arbitrary stuff**
2. Use **parentheses to remember matched stuff** so that you can refer to it later
3. Use **\1, \2 etc to refer to stuff captured** inside the first set of parentheses, the second set and so on.

EDIT1:

### I love Notepad++ :)